# Starting Android app on hotkey?

Tags: java, android

I have such question, can I start my android app, via pressing, for example, home button for three times, or something. I'm interested in starting up, exactly, using hardware buttons (home, back, menu, volume +/-, power, camera ...) ?? Any ideas??

Comment: without your app running, it wont be able to listen to key presses. Its possible you could create a background service that listens to key presses, and when triggered, launches an intent for your app.